# Max length of JSON result to be accessed by a browser for an ios app

Tags: asp.net, ios, json, web-services, httprequest

My web service returns SQL data in JSON format. I call this service from my iOS app. I have two 3 functions in all. First one returns 3000 records. I ran the Uritemplate for this function and i can see the 3000 records. The second and third functions each return 19000 and 27000 records. I add each record into a list and send that in JSON format. But when i access the url in safari/firefox its says "server dropped connection.server busy" message. So i tried to reduce the number of records and around 9300-9400 records is when its failing. I can send 9300 records but in that range it fails. I did this in my web.config

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"  executionTimeout="45" />
  .....

   <system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="100000000"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

But neither work. How can i send that much data. I saved the 9300 records to a file and saw it was 397KB. So i am guessing 19000 records would be double..800KB approx. why can i not see those records on my browser? what more can i add to my config file to send that many records. More questions in queue. If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Its sounds to me like you should consider pagination, as I doubt your UI can reasonably display that many records (regardless what kind of record it is) at one time in any sort of user friendly fashion.

As such, you should focus your efforts on only pulling down the amount of data you can reasonably display at one time plus any extra buffer that might be used for the user to scroll into view while a subsequent request for another page of data is being fulfilled.

This will probably also result in a much better user experience in terms of load times, as the user will not have to wait for some huge request to be fulfilled before they can start interacting with the app.

Comment: Thanks.But this is not for UI. I take those records and send it over web-service to be saved onto core-data. I dont display it all on UI. You can think it like taking a small portion of SQL database and saving it to Core Data on the actual iOS device. I was told that there are no limits to space on the device for app. And the only limit would be the actual free space of the device itself.

Comment: @Phanindar OK. I understand your use case better now.  You still might consider pagination if you wanted to be able to deliver the data updates in smaller increments. You might need to look at server timeouts.